# Update Field When Not Null

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sql-update

I have an update statement that updates fields x, y and z where id = xx.

In the table I have a few different x_created_datetime fields (for different portions of the record that are maintained/entered by different folks). I'd like to write a single query that will update this field if is null, but leave it alone if is not null.

So what I have is:

```
UPDATE newspapers
SET scan_notes = "data",
    scan_entered_by = "some_name",
    scan_modified_date = "current_unix_timestamp"
WHERE id = X
```

What I need is a way to add in the following, but still always update the above:

```
scan_created_date = "current_unix_timestamp"
where scan_created_date is null
```

I'm hoping I can do this without a second transaction to the DB. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do this:

```
UPDATE newspapers
SET scan_notes = "data",    
  scan_entered_by = "some_name",    
  scan_modified_date = "current_unix_timestamp",
  scan_created_date = COALESCE(scan_created_date, "current_unix_timestamp")
WHERE id = X
```

The `COALESCE` function picks the first non-null value.  In this case, it will update the datestamp scan_created_date to be the same value if it exists, else it will take whatever you replace `"current_unix_timestamp"` with.

Comment: It's worth a brief explanation of why this works: coalesce returns the first non-null value in your list of values, so if the scan_created_date is already there, it will set itself to the value that's already there.  If it's null, it will set itself to the current timestamp.

Comment: Won't this update the scan_created_date when it is null?  It looks like he wants to update it where it is not null.

Comment: @tloach - see the explanation.  @JacobM - was already doing it :)

Comment: @ck: This still looks like it's doing the reverse of what he asked.  This will update if scan_created_date is NULL, the query he gives explicitly only updates if scan_created_date is NOT NULL.

Comment: in other words, in his example, a null value will remain null - it will not be set.

Comment: @tloach, you are correct. I typod the part in the code example, but was correct in the english description. I've updated that now. What ck provided is what was desired and works perfectly.

Comment: UPDATE newspapers
SET scan_notes = "data",    
  scan_entered_by = "some_name",    
  scan_modified_date = "current_unix_timestamp",
  scan_created_date = COALESCE(updated_scan_created_date, "current_unix_timestamp")
WHERE id = X


updated_scan_created_date => to specify this is coming from the inputed value not from the table column value.

Answer (score 8):

mySQL has an [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, so you could do:

```
UPDATE newspapers
SET scan_notes = "data",
    scan_entered_by = "some_name",
    scan_modified_date = "current_unix_timestamp"
    scan_created_date = IFNULL( scan_created_date, "current_unix_timestamp" )
WHERE id = X
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that what you're looking for is [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
UPDATE newspapers
SET scan_notes = "data",
    scan_entered_by = "some_name",
    scan_modified_date = "current_unix_timestamp",
    scan_created_date = IF(scan_created_date IS NOT NULL, "current_unix_timestamp", NULL)
WHERE id = X
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use COALESCE() wich returns the first NON-NULL value):

```
scan_created_date = COALESCE(scan_created_date, "current_unix_timestamp")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE newspapers a, newspapers b
SET a.scan_notes = "data",    
  a.scan_entered_by = "some_name",    
  a.scan_modified_date = "current_unix_timestamp",
  b.scan_created_date = "current_unix_timestamp"
WHERE a.id = X AND b.id = X AND b.scan_created_date is not NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Its like equivalent to Oracle's NVL.
You can use it like below in a prepared statement using parameters

```
UPDATE
    tbl_cccustomerinfo
SET
    customerAddress = COALESCE(?,customerAddress),
    customerName =  COALESCE(?,customerName),
    description =  COALESCE(?,description)
WHERE
    contactNumber=?
```